# Swing Applications Always Starting Maximised

Tags: swing, java

Swing applications always start maximised on one of my computers, but not on others. I've posted about this issue on the Sun Java forums without any solution being found. I tried uninstalling the JRE and reinstalling it to see if that would fix it, but it hasn't. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Exactly what applications? All?

Comment: Yep, all of them. It's weird.

Comment: There was a very similar thread over on the sun java fourms last week, are you the same person? If not, I'll try and find it to see if there were any solutions found.
Edit: Sounds like it's you: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5447299

Comment: check what have you used for main frame in setExtendedState()

Comment: Yes, that's my post Rulmeq. I'm convinced it's an issue with the JRE and it's definitely not a problem with my code, as it happens with other applications, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of desperation I reset all of my graphics card settings to their defaults, and now everything is magically fixed. It'd be interesting to know which setting fixed it.